# Does rails scaffold command support generate belongs_to or many to many model middle table migration info?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold, rails-generate

Product,Category is two model on rails3 the relation between them are follow:

product has_and_belongs_to_many categories

category has_and_belongs_to_many products

i can use scaffold generate migration for this two modle use

```
rails g scaffold product name:string
rails g scaffold category name:string
```

but how can i generate the many to many model's middle table migration info,or i need write it manually,if so this is hard for me,hope someone could help me.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#tips-tricks-and-warnings
i foud some useful link,it seems need create the assocation table by myself,if so rails is not such magic in my mind

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Associations#has_and_belongs_to_many
also i found another relevent link,i have another question is how to named assocation table,products_categories or categories_products,if both two model start with c or p character put which model name first in assocation-table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need create this table by yourself

```
   create_table :products_categories, :id => false do |t| 
     t.integer :product_id 
     t.integer :category_id
   end
```

Warning, you need define the :id to false, because this table no need id column. If you have an id column, the table is invalid to be used on has_and_belongs_to_many .

Answer (score 2):

```
rails g model ProductCategories product:references category:references
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `ProductsCategories`?

Comment: I think `ProductCategories` ?